# GPUImage imageFromCurrentFramebuffer returning nil sometimes for GPUImageLookupFilter and it's subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I have been using `GPUImage` for my project and I am getting into this problem where `imageFromCurrentFramebuffer` returns nil for some of the `GPUImageLookupFilter's`.

I subclassed `GPUImageFilterGroup` like in the `GPUImageAmatorkaFilter` my code is as follows:

```
-(MTLookupFilter *) initWithLookupImageName:(NSString *) lookupImageName {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:lookupImageName];
    self.lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
    GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
    [self addFilter:lookupFilter];
    [self.lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter atTextureLocation:1];
    [self.lookupImageSource processImage];
    self.initialFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lookupFilter, nil];
    self.terminalFilter = lookupFilter;
}
return self; 
}
```

I have several of the objects of this class added into an array and I use:

```
- (IBAction)filterAction:(id)sender {
      NSInteger index = arc4random()%self.filtersArray.count;
      id filter = self.filtersArray[index];
      GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.fullImage];
      UIImage *filteredimage = nil;
      [stillImageSource addTarget:filter];
      [stillImageSource processImage];
      [filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
      filteredimage = [filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

      if (filteredimage) {
          self.imageView.image = filteredimage;
      } else {
          NSLog(@"Filtered image is nil");
      }
  }
```

The returned image from `imageFromCurrentFramebuffer` is sometimes nil and I do not understand it's cause. I would be thankful for any help. Sometimes the image is nil even for the filters, `GPUImageAmatorkaFilter`, `GPUImageSoftEleganceFilter` and `GPUImageMissEtikateFilter so I know it is not a problem with my subclass.

Comment: So as it appears, the lookup filters work as they should if they are created at the time of application. i.e. if I create the filters in the 'filterAction method, they work fine. The filters other than lookup filters work fine in an array as well though.

Comment: In the second block of code, `[filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];` should come before `[stillImageSource processImage];`. Try swapping the order of those two.

Comment: Thank you @BradLarson for answering but, doing so made no difference in the final result. Some filters still return nil.

Comment: @Matt hey facing the some problem . if you find the solution then let me know

Comment: @SunnyShah I did not find any solution. However, I create the objects when I need them instead of storing them in an array.

Comment: My case was solved by moving GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource to header it sometimes get released somehow