# GPUImage LookupFilter working only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

This method is used to run a chain of `GPUImageFilter` and return the processed image.

```
    - (UIImage *)runFilterOnImage:(UIImage *)imageToFilter 
    {
        //  Setup the filter chain

        [_filterChain enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(GPUImageFilter *filter, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            if ([filter targets].count > 0) {
                *stop = YES;
                return;
            }

            if (idx < _filterChain.count - 1) {
                GPUImageFilter *nextFilter = [_filterChain objectAtIndex:idx + 1];
                [filter addTarget:nextFilter];
            }
        }];

        //  Process the image

        GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:imageToFilter];

        [stillImageSource addTarget:[_filterChain firstObject]];

        [[_filterChain lastObject] useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        [stillImageSource processImage];

        UIImage *filteredImage = [[_filterChain lastObject] imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:imageToFilter.imageOrientation];
        return filteredImage;
    }
```

where _filterChain is an `NSArray` of `GPUImageFilter` objects.

This method is encapsulated in a custom `FilterItem` class which adds a filter name, thumbnail, etc.

Now using this code once! to run filters on an image works fine. The processing takes almost unnoticeable time.
However, when i call the method again, there is a long delay (~ 3s) after which the returned image is `nil`.

To be more precise, the exact line of code which takes about 3s to execute is `imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:`.

The filter chains i'm using do have "lookup filters" in them: `GPUImageAmatorkaFilter` and `GPUImageMissEtikateFilter`. Is there any problem regarding the lookup (i've added the .pngs to the app bundle - should be fine ?)

Please tell me if the chaining code is just wrong or if this is another problem i'm facing.

**EDIT**

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803436/gpuimage-imagefromcurrentframebuffer-returning-nil-sometimes-for-gpuimagelookupf) which may describe the same problem.

Do I have to create the lookup filters lazily instead of storing them in `_filterChain`?

I think i can narrow the problem down from "returns `nil` sometimes" to "returns `nil` always after the first call".